# Can i use OpenGL features from qt without having any kind of widget?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm trying to compute something on gpu using openGL compute shaders.
But i want to keep this program in terminal, so i don't want any kind of widgets.

For now it looks like i won't be able to call initializeOpenGLFunctions() or any others ogl related functions without getting Segmentation fault.

Header

```
#include <QOpenGLShaderProgram>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions_4_5_Core>

class SolverGPU : public QObject,
                  protected QOpenGLFunctions_4_5_Core
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SolverGPU();

private:
    QOpenGLShaderProgram* program;
};
```

Src

```
SolverGPU::SolverGPU()
{
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    program = new QOpenGLShaderProgram();
    program->addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Compute, ":/shaders/compute.glsl");
    program->link();
    program->bind();
}
```

I've already tried using QOpenGLFunctions instead of QOpenGLFunctions_4_5_Core, that didn't worked.

Comment: You probably need a valid current [`OpenGL` context](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglcontext.html) when calling `QOpenGLFunctions_4_5_Core::initializeOpenGLFunctions`.  Or, create the `QOpenGLContext` with the required spec and use [`QOpenGLContext::functions`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglcontext.html#functions).

Comment: QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent needs QSurface as a parameter. And calling QOpenGLContext::functions() needs context to be current.
Well, i'm almost sure already that there is no way to make this using Qt wrapper

Thanks for replying for my first question here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code works for me.  The box I'm working at right now doesn't support OpenGL 4.5, hence the `downgrade' to 3.3.  The principle's the same though.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QOffscreenSurface>
#include <QOpenGLContext>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core>
#include <QOpenGLShader>
#include <QOpenGLShaderProgram>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  try {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setMajorVersion(3);
    format.setMinorVersion(3);
    format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);

    QOpenGLContext gl_ctx;
    gl_ctx.setFormat(format);
    if (!gl_ctx.create())
      throw std::runtime_error("context creation failed");

    QOffscreenSurface surface;
    surface.create();
    gl_ctx.makeCurrent(&surface);

    QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core opengl_functions;
    if (!opengl_functions.initializeOpenGLFunctions())
      throw std::runtime_error("initialization failed");

    QOpenGLShader vertex_shader(QOpenGLShader::Vertex);
    if (!vertex_shader.compileSourceCode(
          "#version 330 core\n"
          "\n"
          "void main ()\n"
          "{\n"
          "  gl_Position = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
          "}\n"
          )) {
      throw std::runtime_error("vertex shader compilaton failed");
    }

    QOpenGLShader fragment_shader(QOpenGLShader::Fragment);
    if (!fragment_shader.compileSourceCode(
          "#version 330 core\n"
          "\n"
          "layout(location = 0) out vec4 colour;\n"
          "\n"
          "void main ()\n"
          "{\n"
          "  colour = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
          "}\n"
          )) {
      throw std::runtime_error("fragment shader compilaton failed");
    }

    QOpenGLShaderProgram program;
    if (!program.addShader(&vertex_shader))
      throw std::runtime_error("failed to add vertex shader to program");
    if (!program.addShader(&fragment_shader))
      throw std::runtime_error("failed to add fragment shader to program");
    if (!program.link())
      throw std::runtime_error("failed to link failed");
    if (!program.bind())
      throw std::runtime_error("glUseProgram failed");

    app.exec();
  }
  catch (std::exception &ex) {
    std::clog << "\n" << ex.what();
  }
  catch (...) {
    std::clog << "\nunrecognized exception";
  }
  exit(0);
}
```

I've only performed minimal testing but the code shown creates a suitable context, initializes the 3.30 core function set and successfully compiles and links a shader program.

Comment: Yes, that'll do! Thank you a lot